# Query for who you like, who likes you, and mutual likes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

Is there a better way to do this than 3 separate queries?

```
MATCH (you:User {name: "Alexander"})-[:LIKES]->(youLike:User)
RETURN youLike

MATCH (likesYou:User)-[:LIKES]->(you:User {name: "Alexander"})
RETURN likesYou

MATCH (mutualLike:User)-[:LIKES]->(you:User {name: "Alexander"})-[:LIKES]->(mutualLike:User)
RETURN mutualLike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a shot at a single query.

Essentially, find yourself first, optionally find people that you like and collect them, optionally find people that like you and collect them, then return both collections and the intersection of the two.

By matching the node that identifies you and reusing it you match yourself once instead of three times.

Using the collection filter function allowsyou two find the intersection of the two `:LIKES` populations without rematching those nodes.

The `OPTIONAL` keyword allows the query to continue if either `:LIKES` population is empty.

```
MATCH (you:User {name: "Alexander"})
WITH you
OPTIONAL MATCH(you)-[:LIKES]->(youLike:User)
WITH you, collect(youLike) as youLike
OPTIONAL MATCH (likesYou:User)-[:LIKES]->(you)
WITH you, youLike, collect(likesYou) as likesYou
RETURN you
, youLike
, likesYou
, filter(n in youLike where n in likesYou) as mutualLike
```